# How to show a detail page of a product with Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have a project in Laravel and Livewire.

This is my view displaying a list of projects submitted.

```
@forelse ($projects as $index => $project)
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <a href="#" wire:click="showProjectDetails({{ $project->slug }})"
                    class="block p-6 bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-sm shadow-md hover:bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
                    <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-blue-500 dark:text-white">
                        {{ $project->title }}
                    </h5>
                    <p class="my-5">Bugdet Ghc500 - Ghc 700</p>
                    <p class="font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">{{ $project->description }}</p>
                    <ul class="flex gap-4 text-blue-600 mt-5">
                        <li>PHP</li>|
                        <li>Mobile App Development</li>|
                        <li>Database Management</li>|
                        <li>C++</li>
                    </ul>
                </a>
            </div>
        @empty
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <p class="text-4xl">No Projects found</p>
            </div>
        @endforelse
```

When I click on a single project, a new view called show-project should display the details of the particular project that has been clicked.

My Livewire controller

```
public function showProjectDetails($slug)
    {
        return redirect()->route('show-project.details', $slug);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{{ route('show.project_details', ['slug' => $project->slug]) }}">
```

and `web.php` route can be either Controller or Livewire page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sir, however the problem I'm facing now is, the list of the posted projects are displayed fine. And when I click on a single project, it renders the project details page, however on the project details page, I receive this error `Attempt to read property "title" on null`. So the details of that particular clicked project is not displaying.

Comment: You have to set up route model binding correctly. On the project page you can check `@php dd($project) @endphp` and it will be null. Check here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#implicit-model-binding-scoping